# Django external css file problem

Tags: css, django, static

For a couple of days now I have been trying to setup my django project to run my html-template with an external css-file. So far, no succes....

I have installed staticfiles ( Im using django 1.2.4.) and put the 'staticfiles' in INSTALLED_APPS within settings.py and added the following code:

> STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(**file**)), "static")
>
> STATIC_URL='/static/'

My css-file is located under /static/css/stylesheet.css

My html-template has the link

> link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/stylesheet"

After running the server, the page loads just fine. However django cant find my stylesheet...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The static root and url doesn't actually host the files. The static serve option (in the urls.py) mentioned previously is a good option for development and learning, but if you move to a deployment server you should use the static hosting provided by your webserver.

The way the static folders is intended to work is that you add the path locations for each app, project, etc to the static directories setting in settings.py. Then, when you run the command "django-admin.py collectstatic" django pulls all of your directories into your static root. After the first time you run collectstatic, only files that have changed will be copied again. This consolidates multiple static directories into one common place.

[Static files documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `RequestContext` to the view, so it will run through the staticfiles' `CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` (which includes the `STATIC_URL` variable).

```
from django.template.context import RequestContext

context = {'my_other_context': 1}
render_to_response('your_template.html',
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request, context))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I dont understand this. Where is the CONTEXT_PROCESSORS supposed to be placed? 'my_other_context'...what does this mean?

Comment: In your settings.py you should have a CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting which will include the path to the staticfiles context processor.  The my_other_context is just an example of some additional context you may want to pass to the template.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to just use a django.views.static.serve instance like this in the url.py file:

```
(r'^(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': '/path/to/css/'}),
```

Comment: Thanks. When I use this, do I have to remove the 'staticfiles' from my INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: Yes you can remove it if you want, because `django.views.static.serve` takes care of what is needed to serve the static content